# Use variables in DateTime using visual basic

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I currently have this If statement which works perfectly :

```
If (Today > New DateTime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 0, 0)) And (Today < New DateTime(2020, 2, 18, 0, 0, 0)) Then
        deliveryText = "I'm working"
      Else
```

However, now I need to use that same statement but change one of the days for a variable

For example, the variable that I get from the customer is X , which will be replacing the day. I don't know the correct syntaxis on how to make it work, this is how i see it in my head, in this case X = 17

```
If (Today > New DateTime(2020, 2, X - 3, 0, 0, 0)) And (Today < New DateTime(2020, 2, X + 1, 0, 0, 0)) Then
        deliveryText = "I'm working"
      Else
```

Does it make sense?
is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the variable represents an offset from a specific date then you should start with that specific date and then offset, e.g.

```vb
Dim currentDate = Date.Today
Dim rootDate = #2/01/2020# 'Use a date literal if you know the specific value at design time.

Dim startDate = rootDate.AddDays(x - 2)
Dim endDate = rootDate.AddDays(x)

If currentDate > startDate AndAlso currentDate < endDate Then
```

This allows for the month to change if the number of offset days takes you outside the month specified in `rootDate`.